# IMAP Oauth in c#

Tags: c#, oauth, gmail, imap

There are plenty of IMAP clients for C#. However I can't seem to be able to find one that supports the OAuth extensions to use with Gmail.

Has anyone come across any which handles this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems no one is interested in IMAP and OAuth. So I figured out how to do it myself and wrote a short description here:
http://sajadi.co.uk/dflat/2010/06/oauth-for-imap-and-gmail-in-c/

Answer (score 0):

[Mail.dll .NET email component](http://www.limilabs.com/mail) now supports OAuth.

Check out this blog post on [how to access Gmail using OAuth and IMAP](http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth-with-gmail)

Please note that Mail.dll is a commercial product that I helped to create.

Comment: Thanks Pawel for this. I am happy to have kicked it off! ;)